# Mysql number of users per month

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database with the schema with fields

username, timestamp

where timestamp is the date of last activity.

I would like to construct a query in mysql that will give me the number of records, broken up by month, for a specific user.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a log table, with one entry per user per use of the site?  Or an account table with one entry per user period?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're question is posted as number of users per month, but I think you mean number of records per month from a given user.  The query you want is:

```
Select CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(`timestamp`),'-',MONTH(`timestamp)) AS CHAR) as `month`, COUNT(*) as `hits` FROM db.table WHERE `username`='<the_username>'  GROUP BY `month`;
```

Comment: I think? how did you decide that? please write an answer to what he exactly asked so that other users won't confuse

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(*) as counta, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%m") as "_month" 
from users    
where username='YOUR_USER_NAME'
group by _month
order by _month
```

For unix timestamp,use FROM_UNIXTIME

```
SELECT count(*) as counta, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), "%Y-%m") as "_month"
from users    
where username='YOUR_USER_NAME'
group by _month
order by _month
```